# Rack application: Find out where it's mounted before being called

Tags: ruby, server, rack, server-name

I have a simple Rack application where part of its behaviour/configuration changes depending on the location(host and port) where it is mounted.

Rack exposes the current host and port in the [Environment](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC) under `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT`. But these are of course only passed along to the Rack app's `call(env)` method when the first request is made.

Because part of the setup is dependent on the location, I want to read above setting in the `initialize` of my Rack app's class. (How) can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would use theses methods, according to the fact you are in a file which belongs to the directory of your application:

```
working_directory = `pwd`

# or:
working_directory = File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)
```

Comment: In that way I can find out the working directory, but not if I am hosted on 127.0.0.1 or instead on 123.4.5.6 or instead on 987.6.5.4